# I need to upload 5 projects on git lab on the same project but different branches

Tags: git, gitlab

So I'm new to this whole coding world, also new to stack overflow, so sorry If I'm not doing this the right way. 
I need to upload 5 projects on Git Lab, on one project but on different branches, so, I'm stuck and need help.
So far I tried:

- Create a new project on Git Lab
- git init on the local folder
- then push origin (link from git lab)
- git add .

But when I try to add files on the branches... it's not working for me.

Comment: It would be great if you can post some code/image/screenshot for more information on this.

Comment: Why do you have to put 5 projects on the same repository  but different branches? That is not a good approach to git at all. You are better off creating individual repos for each project.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow @hermoiona, what I understand is that you are trying to push local changes to gitlab in different branches. The git commands for this can be as follows:

```
git init
git remote add origin the-web-address-of-gitlab-project
git add .
git commit -m"Message"
git push origin master

git checkout -b branch1
git add .
git commit -m"Message 2"
git push origin branch1

git checkout -b branch3
git add .
git commit -m"Message 3"
git push origin branch3
....
```

and similarly for others.

- **git init**: initialises git.
- **git add .** : Adds/Stages all files and directories within the local git repository for the commit.
- **git commit -m" "** : Commits all the changes with a message
- **git push origin master** : Pushes the local changes to the master branch of gitlab project.
- **git checkout -b nameofbranch** : Transfers the HEAD of file to the branch if no branch of the same name exists a new branch is created.